# Confusion with the index method of a list in python.

Tags: python, indexing

How is this possible?

```
list = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in list:
    print list.index(i),
    list[ list.index(i) ] += 1
```

This prints: 0 1 2 3 (which is understandable)

```
list = [1, 4, 5, 2]
for i in list:
    print list.index(i),
    list[ list.index(i) ] += 1
```

This prints: 0 1 1 0

Comment: How is this possible what? It is working as expected.

Comment: As a side note, you should not name a variable `list`. That's the name of the built-in type and constructor function. If you ever want to, say, make a list out of a set, and you've reused the name `list` to mean something else, you can't do it.

Comment: Meet your new friend [enumerate.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) You can do `for i, e in enumerate([1,4,5,2]): print i, e` and it will do what you think it should. Whenever you are thinking `for loop; wish I had the index of the elements...` Think enumerate...

Comment: Oh I see. lol. I've been using this trick for so long I couldn't even remember how it worked. I guess I can't modify them inside the loop.

Answer (score 5):

`list.index(i)` returns the first index where the value `i` is found in the list.

```
> i = 1
prints: 0
list[0] = 1+1 = 2 -> list = [2,4,5,2]

> i = 4
prints: 1
list[1] = 4+1 = 5 -> list = [2,5,5,2]

> i = 5
prints: 1 #because that's where 5 is first found in the list
list[1] = 5+1 = 6 -> list = [2,6,5,2]

> i = 2
prints: 0 #because that's where 2 is first found in the list
list[0] = 2+1 = 3 -> list = [3,6,5,2]
```

Comment: You should also explain how to fix this: If you want to iterate over unique indices, use `for idx, i in enumerate(lst):`, and then you can use `lst[idx]`, which is guaranteed to be right, instead of `lst[index(i)]`, which may get the wrong position.

Answer (score 2):

If you modify your loop to print out more about what's happening, you can see for yourself:

```
list = [0, 0, 0, 0]
for i in list:
    print i, 'found at', list.index(i), 'in', list
    list [ list.index(i) ] += 1
    print "list'", list

0 found at 0 in [0, 0, 0, 0]
list' [1, 0, 0, 0]
0 found at 1 in [1, 0, 0, 0]
list' [1, 1, 0, 0]
0 found at 2 in [1, 1, 0, 0]
list' [1, 1, 1, 0]
0 found at 3 in [1, 1, 1, 0]
list' [1, 1, 1, 1]
```

And...

```
list = [1, 4, 5, 2]
for i in list:
    print i, 'found at', list.index(i), 'in', list
    list [ list.index(i) ] += 1
    print "list'", list

1 found at 0 in [1, 4, 5, 2]
list' [2, 4, 5, 2]
4 found at 1 in [2, 4, 5, 2]
list' [2, 5, 5, 2]
5 found at 1 in [2, 5, 5, 2]
list' [2, 6, 5, 2]
2 found at 0 in [2, 6, 5, 2]
list' [3, 6, 5, 2]
```